# React Native - Image inside Nested Text, Vertical Align not working

Tags: react-native

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    fontSize: 15,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  insideText: {
    width: 30,
    height: 30,
    alignSelf: 'center',
  },
})  

<Text style={styles.container}>
    <Image style={styles.insideText} source={myImage} />
  test
</Text>
```

When I implement this functionality with Swift
Fixed by setting NSAttachment bounds.

But React Native does not know how to access those parameters.

[image: output of my code]

The output of my code.
How do I center text and images?

can not divide a view into several.
Because the content is flexible, it is not known how many it will be.

Smaller image sizes will center them
The image is too small.
I want to keep the image size.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not the nicest way but you could do this:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    fontSize: 15,
    height: 30,
    paddingTop: (30 - 15) / 2,
    paddingLeft: 30
  },
  insideText: {
    width: 30,
    height: 30,
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you mean by the requirement of flexible content, but nesting an Image within a text does not seem like the way to go.

You'll have less styling flexibility, and are very limited.

To affect what you want without setting absolute positioning, just wrap it and have the icon and text as siblings of a parent View:

```
<View
  style={{
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  }}>
  <Image style={styles.insideText} source={snackIcon} />
  <Text style={styles.container}>test</Text>
</View>
```

Fortunately your styles for insideText and container are fine for this example :)

Here's a snack of the code: 
https://snack.expo.io/@paullyfire/centered-image-text-container

Let me know if you have any issues.